# How to multiply images in Python Wand?

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I'm currently writing a script to generate some textures according to color schemes for a project of mine, and one of the things I need to do is "multiply" the image, much like the layering mode that you can find in Gimp or Photoshop.

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this under Wand.  I know that ImageMagick provides the ability to multiply images by running the composite command with the compose flag.  However, the equivalent in Wand, Image.composite, does not provide any options aside from the second image and the upper-left coordinates, so it only copies and pastes on top of the underlying image.

Am I missing something, or are there better options available?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [`Image.composite_channel()`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.7/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.composite_channel) method?

Answer (score 0):

I dug further.  As far as I can tell, Wand does not support this kind of functionality.  So instead I've gone with Pillow, a fork of the Python Imaging Library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow